# Spring Tools 4 for Eclipse Interface English language error

Tags: spring, eclipse, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

Why does the interface language is different? Example: It shows
"**Recenci g Gzr.."** for **Package Explorer**

[image: cropped]

[image: interface of Spring tools suite]

Comment: If you not on the current versions of either Eclipse or Spring Tools, update.

Comment: I updated both Eclipse and Spring Tools 4 to the latest version but both interfaces had the same problem.

Comment: Is this a plain and fresh Spring Tools 4 installation that shows this behavior? If not, can you give that a try to see if that shows the same behavior? I haven't seen something like this before. Which operating system do you use?

Comment: Yes it is, this problem also occurs in Eclipse IDE too. My Operating system is Windows 11 Home

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This English language error occurs because of the missing font. I just installed Segoe UI regular font then it solved. [https://www.download-free-fonts.com/details/90201/segoe-ui][1]

PS: I figured it out by following these steps in Spring Tool Suite 4.

(Window > Preferences > General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts > View and Editor Folders > double clicking 'Part title fonts')